# How to trim result string value?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<xsl:value-of select="IPADDRESS" />
```

The above line returns the IP address `192.123.201.21` but I want the output to be `192.123.201`. How to split the string at `.` and remove the last token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0 you need to work a little harder at it:

```
<xsl:variable name="lastOctet" select="substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(IPADDRESS, '.'), '.'), '.')" />
<xsl:value-of select="substring(IPADDRESS, 1, string-length(IPADDRESS) - string-length($lastOctet) - 1)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The XPath 1.0 `substring-before` and `substring-after` functions can give you the substring before/after the *first* occurrence of a given separator, but to find the substring before the *last* occurrence you need to use a tail-recursive template

```
<xsl:template name="substring-before-last">
  <xsl:param name="str" />
  <xsl:param name="separator" />
  <xsl:param name="prefix" select="''" /><!-- first segment - no prefix -->

  <xsl:variable name="after-first" select="substring-after($str, $separator)" />

  <xsl:if test="$after-first">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($prefix, substring-before($str, $separator))" />
    <xsl:call-template name="substring-before-last">
      <xsl:with-param name="str" select="$after-first" />
      <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="$separator" />
      <!-- for second and subsequent segments, prepend a $separator -->
      <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="$separator" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

This template keeps writing out segments between separators until it reaches a point where there are no more instances of the separator string.  You would call it by replacing your `xsl:value-of` element with

```
<xsl:call-template name="substring-before-last">
  <xsl:with-param name="str" select="IPADDRESS" />
  <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="'.'" /><!-- note the single quotes -->
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: An IPv4 address **always** consists of four decimal numbers separated by dots. Therefore the task can be safely defined as finding the substring before the *third* occurrence of the separator.

Comment: @michael.hor257k true in this particular case (I've +1'd your answer) but I thought it'd be useful to answer the specific question that was asked - "How to split the string at . and remove the last token?"

Answer (score 0):

This should work (referring to your title: "how to trim result string value?"):

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(IPADDRESS,1,11)" />
```

Can you rely on the `IPADDRESS` element to always have the same structure and content? If so, there is no need to tokenize.

Comment: I am working with XSLT 1.0, and have the different structure and content.

Comment: This works in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0, I believe: http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_substring.html. What do you mean by having "the different structure and content"?

Comment: IP address may be 122.12.12.1, 122.102.102,102,etc have no fixed length.So above solution will not work. And XSLT 2.0 has solution as tokenize but I am working with 1.0

Comment: Then please use the answers given by Ian and Michael.

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT 2.0 you could use `<xsl:value-of select="tokenize(IPADDRESS, '\.')[position() lt last()]" separator="."/>`.